# Create video from many single-frame video files

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have a directory full of videos, each containing only a single frame:

```
foo/0001.flv
foo/0002.flv
foo/0003.flv
...
```

ffmpeg gives the following details about said videos:

```
Input #0, flv, from 'frames/0001.flv':                                                                                                                                                         
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A                                                                                                                                                                    
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 15 tbr, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
```

I am able to achieve what I want by converting all those frames to PNG via
`ffmpeg -i $i.flv $i.png`
and then encoding via `ffmpeg -i %04d.png <encoding params> result.mp4`.

Converting each frame in a separate ffmpeg process takes a long time, though: is there a way to do this in a single pass?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat).

1. Make `input.txt` containing:

   ```
   file '0001.flv'
   file '0002.flv'
   file '0003.flv'
   file '0004.flv'
   file '0005.flv'
   ```
2. Concatenate:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4
   ```

See [FFmpeg Wiki: Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) to see how to generate the list file so you don't have to do it manually.